# SearchView in android the same to google play store

Tags: android-layout, search, layout

I want to use SearchView that it the same to google play store SearchView like picture below but I don't know how do it.

May you show me sample code or google library?
Thank You!

[image: SearchView]

Answer (score 1):

try this my friend
add this **dependency** in **gradle** app file

```
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

**now use below code**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_edit"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:hint="Search anything" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

ask me in case of any query